# On element click get img src attribute value

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have the following html

```
<td class="emailModal" data-name="My name" data-id="myId" data-target="#myModal" data-toggle="modal">
  <div class="someClass">
    <img class="imgClass" width="50%" align="left" src="/Content/images/myImage.png">
  </div>
</td>
```

On the onclick event I'm fetching the `data-name` attribute value using js

```
var name = $(this).data('name');
```

My question is how to fetch the clicked image's `src` value using js

Among the things I've tried:

```
var src = $(this).closest('img').attr('src');
```

Comment: You can't just refer img by its class?...

Comment: @user1765862 `closest` looks up the ascendence chain; if you used `find` instead your proposal would work. ;)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use `$(this).find('img').attr('src')`. Guessing the element click is the `td` element.

Answer (score 1):

Add the following attribute to your element:

```
onclick="getImgSrc(this)"
```

Then add the following javascript:

```
function getImgSrc(param){
var imgSrc = $(param).attr("src");
};
```

You can now include this onclick event to any element on your website to get the img src :)

Please note that the above requires jQuery

Answer (score -2):

I think you can do `$(this).attr('src');`

I have created a JSFiddle to illustrate my answer in practise:

https://jsfiddle.net/jagoldsmith/6jn5obx4/